# What's comparable to Chef for Windows?

Tags: windows, configuration, automation

What's a good tool to automate Windows server configuration, a la Chef on *NIX?

I know that Chef is somewhat working on Windows, but I'm sure there are some more full-featured tools that others are already using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is an old question, but) You can use Chef on Windows now, and it's support has been continually improving.

Comment: +1 despite the necropost

Comment: "Despite"?  Things change!  Let's (attempt to) keep info current!  :-)

Comment: I know, I joke haha

Answer (score 2):

If you have money to burn you can buy [MS System Center Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/systemcenter/cm/default)

Otherwise you can put something pretty close together using group policies and custom scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also (since June 2013) use the [Windows Desired State Configuration PowerShell tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249912.aspx)

This video is actually quite a useful introduction to the new toolset:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/MDC-B302#fbid=InraqmsI9ZP

However, unless you are absolutely certain that you'll never need to provision a single Linux box, I recommend you use Chef.